# influxdb cloud 2 getting Alert Notification failures but can't find reason (no logs or info available)

Tags: influxdb-2

I am using Influxdb Cloud v2 and have set it up to send Alerts to an HTTP endpoint. The Alert History shows Alerts are being triggered, and Notifications in Alert History shows the correct time stamps, check, rule, and endpoint. However the "Sent" records show a yellow triangle with "!" inside, which I assume means a problem sending to the endpoint. I can't find logs or any information on what this failure might be. Is there some way to find out what is failing or what the error message is?